# Please describe the function of this expression

Tags: perl

Here is my Perl code

I want know exactly what happens in the expression `join '', @{ $imap->top($i) }`

```
use Email::Simple;
use Net::IMAP::Simple::Gmail;

my $server = 'imap.gmail.com';

my $imap = Net::IMAP::Simple::Gmail->new($server);
$imap->login( 'user@gmail.com' => 'user@742' );

my $nm = $imap->select('INBOX');
print "Emails Count == ", $nm;
print "\n";

print "How many emails you wants to read == ";
my $count = <STDIN>;

for (my $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ ) {
    my $es = Email::Simple->new( join '', @{ $imap->top($i) } );
    printf( "[%03d] %s\n\t%s\n", $i, $es->header('From'), $es->header('Subject') );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
join '', @{$imap->top($i)}
```

What this does:

First we get the value of the variable `$imap`. It's a local variable (declared as `my $imap` above), and it better contain an object because we're about to call a method on it. (Technically it could also contain a class name, but `->new` usually returns an object.)

Then we get the value of the variable `$i`, which is a local variable in the `for` loop (usually those are written `for my $i (1 .. $count)`, though). We pass it as an argument to the `top` method on the `$imap` object.

This method then (hopefully) returns a reference to an array because we're about to dereference it. (Technically it could also return an object with an overloaded `@{}` operation, but that's less likely.)

We dereference the arrayref, which gives us an array. `join` supplies list context to this operation, so we get the contents of the array as a list.

Finally `join` takes the values in the list, stringifies them, and concatenates them (using `''` as the separator, i.e. no separator). The result is a single string.

Answer (score -1):

`@BLOCK` is identical to `@NAME`, except BLOCK must return a reference to the array to use.

`$imap->top($i)` apparently returns a reference to an array, in which case `@{ $imap->top($i) }` returns the elements of that array.